# it possible to impersonate from an impersonated Google service account account in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, impersonation, service-accounts, google-iam

I'm working with multiple Google Cloud projects and need to impersonate multiple users to perform certain actions on their behalf.

My question is, is it possible to impersonate from an impersonated Google account in Google Cloud? If so, what is the best way to achieve this? I know on AWS you can "double assume" a role with the STS service.

I've tried searching for information on this topic, but I haven't been able to find any clear answers also tried to do this in the python SDK but could not succeed:

Lets say we have service account A with TokenCreator role on Service Account B with TokenCreator role on service account C.

```
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials
service_account_b_impersonated_credentials = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
    source_credentials=source_credentials_a,
    target_principal=source_credentials_b,
    target_scopes=[],
    lifetime=500,
)

service_account_c_impersonated_credentials = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
        source_credentials=service_account_b_impersonated_credentials,
        target_principal=service_account_c,
        target_scopes=[],
        lifetime=500,
    )
```

but when using the new credentials, I can't really do anything.

In the CLI I know I can use the --impersonate flag when executing an action such as list vms however didn't find a CLI command equivalent to STS on AWS to really act as the principal for all actions

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK not possible, you’re looking for GCP when using gcloud, API requests or client libraries is not possible like situations in AWS. See the best possible approach is [Managing service account impersonation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts) for more details. Every time you impersonate a service account you should do it clearly since you are unable to store the credentials like in AWS.

Comment: What do you mean by "but when using the new credentials, I can't really do anything."? Normally, you have a token, generated on behalf of something else, and that credential is enough to perform operations. however, in your case, the token is generated on behalf the service account C. You will have only the permission granted on the service account C, the other permission (A and B) are not taken into account

Comment: The problem is with `target_scopes=[],`. You are creating credentials with no `scopes` (permissions).

Comment: Found the answer- YOU CAN DO THIS.

With the deligates argument passed to the impersonated_credentials function.

https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.auth.impersonated_credentials.html#:~:text=delegates%20(Sequence